# Where to place the adverb?

Tags: adverbs

Im very confused about the answer provided by a grammarbook.
This is a exercise regarding adverbs.

In the exercise, I am supposed to rewrite the sentence in a correct order.

Case 1

**My answer:** Please gather here at 5 sharp on Tuesday morning.

**Answer provided by the book:** Please gather here on Tuesday morning at 5 sharp.

Case 2
*My answer is the same as the one provided by the book.*

**Answer provided:** She is going to meet him near the coffee lounge at noon on Wednesday.

I just don't understand why in case 1 it is wrong to put "At 5 sharp" before "Tuesday" ,but in case 2 it is fine to put "at noon" before "Wednesday".

Thank you!

Comment: Look at this [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/the-royal-order-of-adverbs).

Answer (score 1):

You are right in both cases, but so is the grammar book. Both forms are grammatically impeccable.

There might be a slight difference in emphasis. In your version of the first one I imagine a school teacher telling a class about to go on a trip'... at 5 sharp' groans from the class' on Tuesday morning'. The grammar book's version gives the impression that 5 is quite a normal time to gather.

Answer (score 0):

There is something known as the 'Royal Order of Adverbs'. The correct order is not fixed, but there are definite trends.

Look at this [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/the-royal-order-of-adverbs).